# 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:' XCode5

Tags: iphone, uitableview, xcode5

I am having a problem with the TableView, I did not have in older Xcode version, I am just creating basic cells in UITableView but I get next error.

*'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'*

Here is the code in .m

> // numero de secciones a definir

```
>-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView: (UITableView*) tableView 
{
    return 1;
}

>// numero de celdas en total

>-(NSInteger) tableView : (UITableView *) tableView numberOfRowsInSection: (NSInteger)section 
{
      return 5;
}

>// formato de las celdas, títulos, imágenes...

>-(UITableViewCell *)tableview : (UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath 
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[ UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

>    // configure the cell...

    return cell;

}
```

Any suggestion? THX

Answer (score 0):

`-(UITableViewCell *)tableView : (UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath`
With a capital "V" at tableView